# Serial to Stereo cable?

Tags: cable, rs232, 3.5mm

While going through some (really) old computer parts I came across a very interesting cable: a female RS232 (9-pin serial) to 3.5mm stereo jack.

Any ideas what this cable might have been used for? (it's not a makeshift DIY cable)

[image]

I remember having an old Fritz ISA > ISDN card using a RS232 to RJ45 connection.

Comment: Also used for Monarch Pathfinder label printers, for uploading files/firmware to the Rom-Dos memory segments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some devices (such as graphing calculators) use 3.5mm jacks to transmit data. They use similar signals to normal serial ports, but use a different connector.

Comment: close, i eventually found the corresponding device, it's a data logger for a cold storage, logging temperatures from various sensors

Comment: That is the type of cable that iogear ships with their KVM (and maybe more) to upgrade the firmware.

Comment: Currently still new devices which uses these type of cables are sold today: http://www.conrad.com/ce/en/product/101367/Voltcraft-CM-100-CO2-Meter

Answer (score 3):

Here's one use I found online: [RapidRun DB9 to 3.5mm Adapter](http://www.projectorzone.com/Cables-to-Go-42165?r=1)

[image: Cable image]

Quote:

> Eliminate the need to run all new
>   cables for RS-232 control of your
>   Audio/Video system. RapidRun's new
>   RS-232 Adapter gives you the
>   flexibility to use existing 3.5mm
>   stereo audio cables or DB9 cables to
>   run 3 conductor RS-232 control signals
>   between your control unit and your
>   video display. This product can be
>   used with all of the DB9 Break-Away
>   Wall Plates and Flying Leads designed
>   for the RapidRun system. RapidRun
>   RS-232 Adapter Features: Supports
>   transmission of serial control signals
>   including RS-232. Fully molded DB9 and
>   3.5mm connectors provide excellent strain relief. Ideal for use with
>   computers, projectors, and any control
>   unit/display requiring 3 conductor
>   RS-232 serial control. Note: Not all
>   serial control methods are supported
>   by this adapter. This product is
>   intended only for use with 3-wire
>   RS-232 control cables with common
>   ground (pin 5), transmit data (pin 3),
>   and receive data (pin 2). For the
>   exact pinout of your audio/video
>   equipment please contact the
>   manufacturer.

Comment: that's exactly the cable ... however, i'm still puzzled how it came into my posession, as i certainly don't have any such 'control units' or RapidRun systems :)

Answer (score 2):

They are typically used as a pinout for digital cameras.

Comment: quite possible, although i only have 2 digi cams (not much of a photographer myself, and older 4 MP Samsung and a 10 MP Fuji, and that cable is probably older than the Samsung. it's not an accessory that i can find any reference in the manuals for either.

Answer (score 2):

There are some devices (like say a RAID box I have at work) that use a 3.5mm jack instead of a standard 9 pin port to access their built-in console.

Answer (score 2):

I found a cable like this too, and finally figured it out that it came with my old late 1990s Olympus D-360L digital camera. It was used to transfer pictures to the computer (before card readers became common) and as I recall it would use a lot of battery transferring the pictures.

Answer (score 1):

since you only really need three lines to do serial communication (and in this case we are not using hardware flow control, which would require two extra lines), a DE-9 to stereo jack is all you need for serial communication with anything with an embedded microprocessor.

The two cases I've used this are a serial programming cable to a TI cable modem, so you could get boot messages and command line access for firmware upgrade purposes; and a OneTouch UltraMini Glucose meter. Here the parent company will sell you an overpriced cable just so you can download your timestamped historic testing data into their "free" software app.